# What is the use of "defined('YII_DEBUG') or" in "defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', false);"?

Tags: yii, yii2

In the `defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', false);` line of code we are checking if debug has defined previously it will do nothing but if not it will set to `false`.

I did not get this I mean what if we want to override previous value and why we cant simply do `define('YII_DEBUG', false);` why it necessary to check previous value if we don't want to use that?

Comment: `or` is logical operator. so, it works like `$a or $b` =>  `TRUE if either $a or $b is TRUE.`. for more info [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Comment: let suppose it has been defined to true but we want it to false so how with 'or' second statement will run i.e. the statement define('YII_DEBUG', false);?

Comment: see [define()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didnt do it but you are not clear about my question, we can only change the YII_DEBUG value in /web/index.php. one more thing if YII_DEBUG has defined anywhere else but after that if we want to change its value what to do for that as 'or' will not change it and it is constant too so cant change its value?

---

Yes, you are very wrong... You can declare the YII_DEBUG value anywhere where you want, but... if it is redefined:
Notice: Constant YII_DEBUG already defined in...
I think thats the reason of defined() or... TO PREVENT THIS ERROR

Answer (score 2):

You can just change it to `true` or `false` to a page on the fly by just doing this:

```
define('YII_DEBUG', true);
```

In such cases `defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', false);` comes in handy it checks if `YII_DEBUG` was `true` or `false`, if it finds `YII_DEBUG` has already been set to `true` or `false` somewhere else then it doesn't executes the `or` part.

This `defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);` is equivalent to

```
if (!defined('YII_DEBUG')) {
    define('YII_DEBUG', true);
}
```

So, you see it checks if `YII_DEBUG` has been defined somewhere else, if not then it sets to `true` in this case.

**Edit:**

To debug any page on the fly, you can just do this:

```
if (isset($_GET['debug'])) define('YII_DEBUG', true);
```

of course you will have to change your url then, for example:

`www.example.com/site/myAction` to `www.example.com/site/myAction/debug/true`
and remove it from `index.php`

**EDIT 2:**

Its not mandatory to define `YII_DEBUG` in `index.php`, it is aleady defined in `Yii` applications, you can find it in root `yii.php` file in case of `Yii2` and in case of `Yii1` its defined in `framework/YiiBase.php`

Comment: I didnt do it but you are not clear about my question, we can only change the YII_DEBUG value in  /web/index.php. one more thing if YII_DEBUG has defined anywhere else but after that if we want to change its value what to do for that as 'or' will not change it and it is constant too so cant change its value?

Comment: ok if it is  but after that if we want to change its value what to do for that as 'or' will not change it and it is constant too so cant change its value?

Comment: @Ren you can change the value anywhere in your application, check my updated answer.

Comment: but what if it is prev. defined? it a constant so how can we set it to true or false interchangeably and we want to change it from prev value?

Answer (score 1):

The

```
<?php
  defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
  defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');
```

are defined in `yourApp/web/index.php`

and this costant define a level of debug info. 
In development enviroment normally this flag is set to true and then in  in case of error there are show detailed information regarding the error and the code gerating the error, if false not or few information are show.

Tipically in production eviroment this costant is set to false. so minus information are show to the user.

for the defined or define

is the costant is already defined the not need define otherwise php define the constat. see php doc http://php.net/manual/en/function.defined.php
`defined — Checks whether a given named constant exists`

You can find more information in Yii2 doc http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-handling-errors.html

Comment: thank you but here I know the concept of YII_DEBUG, I just cant get the logic of 'or' statement as I mentioned in my question. why it is nedd to check yii_debug is defined if we just can assign true or false to it?

Comment: This is tipical for php constant creation show PHP doc for this

Comment: Sorry but why downvoting the answer is correct and my comment are appropriated.

Comment: You gave a correct answer but not to the question, which is "Why is this pattern typical?"

Comment: but Constant cant change their values so how can they could be true or false?

Comment: if YII_DEBUG has defined anywhere else but after that if we want to change its value what to do for that as 'or' will not change it and it is constant too so cant change its value? so confuse why there is true and false value for it?

Comment: do we need to check where it is previously defined if it is and changed it value there?

Comment: @Ren the constant are constant and can't be changed. This instruction are only for test if the constant is defined and not for change the value. If the constant is  not defined you can define it and assign the value, otherwise you should get an error

Comment: suppose if it is defined to true somewhere and we want it to false so what to do for that as it has been defined and a constant too. so what to do in that situation?

Comment: In this situation you should edit the yourApp/web/index.php code (where is defined) and change here  the value. For this Yii2 suggest two enviroment (dev env whit the constant YII_DEBUG true and prod env whit YII_DEBUG false. So edit the  web/ index.php code if you need a verbose debugeer env....

Answer (score 1):

The error handler adjusts the error display according to the value of the constant `YII_DEBUG`. When `YII_DEBUG` is true (meaning in debug mode), the error handler will display exceptions with detailed call stack information and source code lines to help easier debugging. And when `YII_DEBUG` is false, only the error message will be displayed to prevent revealing sensitive information about the application.

Have a look at [YII_DEBUG](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-handling-errors.html) and [YiiBase.php](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/c3dc6a11964acb8042ee0f58bd21785640d87572/framework/YiiBase.php) and [yii.php](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/633e54866d54bf780691baaaa4a1f847e8a07e23/framework/yii.php)

Comment: thank you but here I know the concept of YII_DEBUG, I just cant get the logic of 'or' statement as I mentioned in my question. why it is nedd to check yii_debug is defined if we just can assign true or false to it?

Comment: one more confusing thing is  Constant cant change their values so how can they could be true or false interchangeable?

Answer (score 1):

`defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', false)` checks if the constant `YII_DEBUG` was defined (regardless of its value), and if it wasn't defined earlier it defines the constant as `false`.

The line ensures the constant is defined so it can be used and its first part (`defined('YII_DEBUG') or`) ensures this line won't override it to `false` if it was set to `true` earlier.

Comment: so what to do in case if it is defined to true anywhere else and we want to change it to false what to do for that? do we need to change its value at that place where it is previously defined?