# Where YII_DEBUG can be defined?

Tags: yii2

By default Yii2 generates file `web/index.php` with `defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);` line. It's entry point of any page on site. And this the first line of a code. So checking for defined `YII_DEBUG` seems meaningless. I suppose this constant can be defined in something else place. But can't find where to do it.

In my personal case I have a local version of site and want to enable this constand for debugging purposes but don't want to change `web/index.php`. This file is under VCS (git) and I don't want to accidentally enabled debug in production.

StackOverflow has allready similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566178/what-is-the-use-of-definedyii-debug-or-in-definedyii-debug-or-define). But it targeted on other sense and didn't give answer on my question. So I just created a new question.

Comment: To be honest, basic template is not really prepared for using it with VCS. One of the first things you want to do with it, is to add some support for local settings (like debug mode or DB credentials) that won't be versioned by VCS.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the `index.php` is default entry point for Yii app, you can still create your own entry point, include the `index.php` in it and set web server to use that file instead of `index.php`.

For example you can create `custom-entry.php` like this:

```php
<?php

define('YII_DEBUG', false);

// do something ...

require index.php;
```

Or you can define `YII_DEBUG` in some script that is run at start of each request by [`auto_prepend_file`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) directive.

But those are not exactly best options how to deal with your case.
In your case I would suggest to simply set your versioning system to ignore local changes of `index.php` file. For example if you are using GIT you can use [`skip-worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_skip_worktree_bit) flag to do that. I don't know CVS much so I'm not sure how exactly it is done with that.

Answer (score 0):

Yii does it like that

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
```

which means that if it's not defined already - define it.

This is a proper place to define it. The above statement is just in case somehow you got this already defined by any mean which Yii will honor.